# Can you see where my unmatched block nesting is wrong? I just can't seem to see it? MASM

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm

New to assembly. Working on printing a copy of incremented values with C++ and MASM and it looked fine to me.
I got this error:

```
..\..\..\..\Downloads\MASM\project.asm(24): error A2005: symbol redefinition : Store
..\..\..\..\Downloads\MASM\project.asm(32): fatal error A1010: unmatched block nesting : Store
```

```
CONSOLE     equ     -11
KEYBOARD    equ     -10

extrn   Store:          PROC
extrn   increment:      PROC
extrn   Show:           PROC
extrn   ExitProcess:    PROC    

.data
.data?
c1      byte    ?   ;pass in usual reg  /byte=8-bit char                    char
s1      word    ?   ;pass in usual reg  /word=16-bit short                  short
us1     word    ?   ;pass in usual reg  /word=16-bit short                  unsigned short
i1      dword   ?   ;pass in usual reg  /dword=32-bit int or long int       int
ull1    qword   ?   ;offset 48,56,64    /qword=64-bit long long int         unsigned long long int
ll1     qword   ?   ;offset 48,56,64    /qword=64-bit long long int         long long int
uc1     byte    ?   ;offset 48,56,64    /byte=8-bit char                    unsigned char

.code

Store       PROC
         mov    rcx, c1             ;store param1
         mov    rdx, s1             ;store param2
         mov    r8, us1             ;store param3
         mov    r9, i1              ;store param4
         mov    r10, ull1           ;store param5
         mov    r11, ll1            ;store param6
         mov    r12, uc1            ;store param7
Store       ENDP

Increment   PROC
         inc    c1                  ;increment param1
         inc    s1                  ;increment param2
         inc    us1                 ;increment param3
         inc    i1                  ;increment param4
         inc    ull1                ;increment param5
         inc    ll1                 ;increment param6
         inc    uc1                 ;increment param7
Increment   ENDP

Show        PROC
       Display
Show        ENDP

Display:
    mov      c1, rcx            ;
    mov      s1, rdx            ;
    mov      us1, r8            ;
    mov      i1, r9         ;
    mov      ull1, r10          ;
    mov      ll1, r11           ;
    mov      uc1, r12           ;
    pop      rcx                ;
    pop      rdx                ;
    pop      r8                 ;
    pop      r9                 ;
    pop      r10                ;
    pop      r11                ;
    pop      r12                ;
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't even have 32 lines. What is the rest of the code?

Comment: Edited. All of it is now updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `Store`, `Increment` and `Show` as `extrn`, so you can't define them here afterwards - the are already defined, as coming from an external source!

Remove those `extrn` definitions. (Only `ExitProcess` has to stay since it's *actually* coming from an external source.)

*The "unmatched" part is probably just a result of the previous error and the `Store PROC` line being ignored due to the error, which will make `Store ENDP` unmatched. So, this error should go away as well once the `extrn` issue is fixed.*

Comment: Thanks greatly. That was my issue! Cleared it right away.

Comment: @JennyNguyen: if this fully answers your question, you can mark it as the accepted answer using the checkmark under the vote arrows.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for letting me know